# React component event handler - can't get access to event

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, reactjs, event-handling

This is a basic JavaScript question, but nevertheless sent me googling for a while. Based on [this article](https://www.peterbe.com/plog/onchange-in-reactjs), the below code should work, however I get `event.target is not a function` error in `saveBubble`. When I try `event` in debugger, the error reads `Uncaught: illegal access`. `arguments` array has the needed event, but why doesn't it work when I call `event`?

```
export default class Bubble extends Component {
  saveBubble(event) {
    Bubbles.insert({
      text: event.target.attr('value') // <- throws an error here
    })
  }

  body() {
    const { text } = this.props.bubble;

    if (text) {
      return text;
    }
    else {
      return (
        <input type='text' onBlur={ this.saveBubble.bind(this) }/>
      )
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className='bubble-wrapper'>
        <div className='body'>
          { this.body() }
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: My guess is that `this` in the `body()` function isn't what you think it is. Try binding it in your `render()`.

Comment: @ivarni In both `saveBubble` and `body`, `this` is the Bubble object

Comment: I've also noticed that if I ask for event, it gives me the "Uncaught illegal access" error. But If I ask for event.target it seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you probably want `event.target.value` instead of `event.target.attr('value')`. This will give you the current value in the input element as discussed in the [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html).

My guess is that you're actually getting `event.target.attr is not a function` as an error message, as the dom element (like event.target) doesn't have this method, like say, a jquery object would.

To add a little more clarity, I believe this should work for you:

```
saveBubble(event) {
  Bubbles.insert({
    text: event.target.value
  })
}
```

Comment: You are right. It's late into the night, and I misread the error. I'm still perplexed as to why it was throwing me the illegal access error in console.

Comment: Yeah, I've never seen that one myself before. A quick google shows at least a few other people are perplexed by it as well, so you're not alone.